# Meteor File Change Watcher is taking too long to recognize changes

Tags: meteor

My Meteor file change watcher is taking forever to detect my file changes and refresh the browser, sometimes even longer than a minute. This makes developing a real pain.

My Meteor is running inside an Ubuntu-VM. The projects folder lies in my OSX and is mounted inside the VM. So I'm aware that inotify/kqueue won't work, so Meteor should fallback to stat polling.

I even set the environment variables according to [this post](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/file-change-watcher-efficiency.md), but the behavior is still the same.

```
METEOR_WATCH_FORCE_POLLING=true
METEOR_WATCH_POLLING_INTERVAL_MS=500
```

Is there any way to fix this annoying behavior?

The folder from OSX is mounted as a **nfs** share btw.

**Update:**

I did some testing and there is no difference if the application has a big amount of packages or is taking long to build, even with the very basic app you get after *meteor create* I still get the same behavior.

If I change a file in the VM (so that inotify works) the refresh is happening instantly.

Comment: This may also be caused by a very long build process. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: I don't think so, it happens even on very basic apps like the todos-example.

Comment: happens to me too (osx mavericks)

Comment: I've tracked it to source (safe-pathwatcher.js) and it seems it's not a bug in meteor itself but rather in node...

Answer (score 1):

I've have apps in production that incrementally become slower when adding packages, both 3rd party and private packages. I also discovered that adding 3rd libs directly on the client/lib increases the reloading time.

I'm not sure if Meteor 1.0.2 actually solved the problem of watching the directory efficiently.

Comment: I just ran a test with the very basic app you get after running 'meteor create' and the behavior is still the same. Sometimes I get lucky and the refresh fires after 10 seconds or it takes 40 seconds, it's just random.

Comment: Same thing here. Although the latest Meteor version actually improved a lot the performance. Those 10 seconds are weird but I'm using a quad-core 2.8Ghz, up to 4 Ghz with PCI SSD. I noticed that on my previous machine, it was a nightmare. Could you share your git?

Comment: It's happening on the very basic application. For example I just created an application with 'meteor create' and already have this kind of problem. So it is not application dependent.

Comment: And it is quite odd, it may be a performance issue, it is running in a vm, but to go through 3 files and watch for changes wouldn't take 40 seconds I bet.

Comment: In a VM scenario it really depends on the VM software. I remember the times when I was using a VM with Linux for solving algorithms problems in C and the performance on the host was 5-12x times faster. Don't forget that Meteor is really heavy in requirements. Chrome V8 Engine + Node.js + Meteor. I guess no one ever speaks about the need to have a fast computer for developing with Meteor. I've teammates that suffer a lot from this.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Meteor are you using?

Much of this lag-reloading issue was addressed on Meteor 1.0.2. While it still takes some time, I would say was ~5x faster on my experience.

Comment: I'm on version 1.0.2.1